# how to remove WordPress default comment system

Tags: comments

Hello I what to remove WordPress default comment system and I want to use facebook comment system instead .
Can anyone please tell me how to remove default comment system of WordPress .
And also keep old comments on post.
Thanks.
(P.s - give me code snippet or tutorial reference I'm begginer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your functions.php it removes the comment hooks that are default with Wordpress. If you ever want to reenable the comments just remove this code from your functions.php

```
// Add to existing function.php file
// Disable support for comments and trackbacks in post types
function df_disable_comments_post_types_support() {
    $post_types = get_post_types();
    foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
        if(post_type_supports($post_type, 'comments')) {
            remove_post_type_support($post_type, 'comments');
            remove_post_type_support($post_type, 'trackbacks');
        }
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'df_disable_comments_post_types_support');
// Close comments on the front-end
function df_disable_comments_status() {
    return false;
}
add_filter('comments_open', 'df_disable_comments_status', 20, 2);
add_filter('pings_open', 'df_disable_comments_status', 20, 2);
// Hide existing comments
function df_disable_comments_hide_existing_comments($comments) {
    $comments = array();
    return $comments;
}
add_filter('comments_array', 'df_disable_comments_hide_existing_comments', 10, 2);
// Remove comments page in menu
function df_disable_comments_admin_menu() {
    remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'df_disable_comments_admin_menu');
// Redirect any user trying to access comments page
function df_disable_comments_admin_menu_redirect() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ($pagenow === 'edit-comments.php') {
        wp_redirect(admin_url()); exit;
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'df_disable_comments_admin_menu_redirect');
// Remove comments metabox from dashboard
function df_disable_comments_dashboard() {
    remove_meta_box('dashboard_recent_comments', 'dashboard', 'normal');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'df_disable_comments_dashboard');
// Remove comments links from admin bar
function df_disable_comments_admin_bar() {
    if (is_admin_bar_showing()) {
        remove_action('admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_comments_menu', 60);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'df_disable_comments_admin_bar');
```

and if any comments already exist you can remove the tables themselves from the database using phpMyAdmin or MySQL console.

```
TRUNCATE wp_commentmeta; 
TRUNCATE wp_comments;
```

Its probably safer to just use

```
DELETE FROM wp_comments;  
DELETE FROM wp_commentmeta;
```

Comment: Where to add "TRUNCATE " code .

Comment: does your site currently have comments?

Comment: Yes . Actually it's a demo site and some of my post showing comment are closed

Comment: I updated my post with the answer they are both MySQL Commands which can be run from phpmyadmin or mysql console

Comment: Why some post showing facebook comment plugins box for comment and below that it's showing "comments are closed".

Comment: most likely because its a different post or page type. I dont your what your post or page types are you can modify the first function to add more types `function df_disable_comments_post_types_support() {
    $post_types = get_post_types();
    foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
        if(post_type_supports($post_type, 'comments')) {
            remove_post_type_support($post_type, 'comments');
            remove_post_type_support($post_type, 'trackbacks');
        }
    }
}`

Comment: `remove_post_type_support($post_type, 'YOUR POST TYPE HERE');`

Comment: Your welcome you can also add `.nocomments { display: none; }` to your css to remove the "comments are closed" messages as well! Please accept as answer if all is working thanks!